# Print output of grep command to indent lines as waterfall model

Tags: shell, grep, output

My grep output , should display lines with increment of indent by one in each subsequent line.

grep command output is :

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that the university that assigned this has a tutoring service. Have you even done any research or tried anything on your own?

Comment: You could do this with awk or sed and a for loop. What have you tried?

Comment: Hello Nasir & Grace ! Thanks for your response. I am not technical person and not student either. Was trying to do some automation of function action and need to sniff log for it. I tried different loop methods and no success also, it’s not worth putting my code on this forum … appreciate if you guys can help

Comment: Please post the actual text from the image instead.  Use the `{}` formatting tool to indent the lines as needed. Thank you!

Comment: As pseudocode:
myvar=" "
output= grep "step:" myfile
for i in output
i=sed -e "s/^/ $myvar/"
echo $i
$myvar += " "

Comment: step : 1 : axcbghji
step : 2 : Fhffhvbj
step : 3 : Gdseyiknbcf
step : 4 : Hccrtujbb

Comment: @HM569788 please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/667818/edit) your post, remove the image and make it text only. Also state your command and what you have tried before. It is better to start somewhere so one can see where your problem lies. Best is to also provide example data with given input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`, we may output each line of input indented by the number of spaces corresponding to the lines number in the file, minus 1.

```bsh
grep ... | awk '{ printf "%2$*1$s\n", NR+length-1, $0 }'
```

The `printf` format string used here specifies to output the second string parameter (which is `$0`, the current line) with a field width given by the first parameter (`NR+length-1`, the ordinal number of the current line in the input, plus the length of the line, minus 1). The effect of this is that you get the lines outputted in a staggered fashion, which was precisely the effect you wanted.

Most non-GNU implementations of `awk` do not support this more advanced use of `printf` formats, so you need to solve it differently.

```bsh
grep ... | awk '{ print indent $0 } { indent = indent " " }'
```

The above may be easier to understand than the first `awk` command.  We're using a variable that we call `indent`.  This variable only contains spaces, and we add a new space character to it for each line of input after outputting the current line prefixed by the current value of `indent`.

In both of the pipelines above, `grep ...` symbolizes the `grep` command that you mention in passing in your question.